# No message in display table

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, struts, displaytag

I am expecting "Nothing found to display" in my display table when there is no data but ?I am not getting that message .Page is just blank

my code snippet

```
<display:table name="dpinforce" export="true" pagesize="20" sort="list" id="data1" requestURI="" class="tablelist">
        <display:setProperty name="export.csv" value="false"/>
        <display:setProperty name="export.xml" value="false"/>
        <display:setProperty name="export.excel.filename">DPInforce_<%=oAppUtil.getSystemDateTime()%>.xls


        </display:setProperty>

        <display:column title="PolId" sortable="true" property="polId"></display:column>
        <display:column title="Pol Infc DT" sortable="true" property="polINFCDT"></display:column>
        <display:column title="Aura Stat" sortable="true" property="auraStat"></display:column>
        <display:column title="Plan" sortable="true" property="plan"></display:column>
        <display:column title="Branch" sortable="true" property="branch"></display:column>
        <display:column title="Created On" sortable="true" property="createdOn"></display:column>
</display:table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was checking the condition in if clause andif its true then it was displaying the table and when false I had not written the code.After writing else part its working.